# How to load back old input(s) of check box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I want to load my old input(s) of my check-boxes back in my View.
The problem happened when I tried to edit my object.
I used to deal with old input before, but this one seem to be different.

Here what I did on my Create View

```
{{ Form::label('export_frequency' , 'Export Frequency', array('class'=> 'required cool-blue'))}} <br>
@foreach (ExportFrequency::all() as $export_frequency)
<input type="checkbox" name="export_frequencies[]" value="{{ $export_frequency->id }}" id="{{ $export_frequency->id }}">
{{$export_frequency->name}} <br>
@endforeach
```

That will generate this :

[image]

Now when I Edit my object, I want this check-boxes to stay as their old input.

Can someone please give me some tip(s) on this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get this to work. Here is my solution :

```
{{ Form::label('export_frequency' , 'Export Frequency', array('class'=> 'required cool-blue'))}} <br>

<?php 

$frequencies = $catalog_download->export_frequencies()->get(); 
$array = array(); 

?>

@foreach($frequencies as $frequency) 
    <?php array_push($array,$frequency->id); ?> 
@endforeach 


@foreach (ExportFrequency::all() as $export_frequency)

    {{ Form::checkbox('export_frequencies[]', '$export_frequency->id', in_array($export_frequency->id,$array)); }}      
    {{$export_frequency->name}} 

    <br>

@endforeach
```

Comment: You can save a few lines with `$array = $catalog_download->export_frequencies()->lists('id');`